# Retrieving a string from server

Tags: java

I am trying to make a file sharing java application.
I am making two separate projects, the server and the client. The server side has files stored, and the client may request to download files from the server, or upload files to the server, or retrieve the list of files from the server.

I have a problem in retrieving files from the server. I have made a method to retrieve files, but when the method runs, the program hangs, without any response.

Here's my code for retrieving files (for the client, quite obviously):

```
public void retrieveFileData() throws IOException {
    Socket theSocket = new Socket(this.theHostIP, this.portNumber);
    PrintWriter messageWriter = new PrintWriter(theSocket.getOutputStream(),
            true);
    messageWriter.write("REFRESH");
    BufferedReader filesReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            theSocket.getInputStream()));
    this.retrievedFiles = filesReader.readLine();
    theSocket.close();
}
```

And here's the code for the server side:

```
ServerSocket theServerSocket = new ServerSocket(this.portNumber);
Socket theClientSocket = theServerSocket.accept();
BufferedReader inputReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            theClientSocket.getInputStream()));
PrintWriter outputWriter = new PrintWriter(
            theClientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
String line = inputReader.readLine();

while (true) {
    if (line.startsWith("REFRESH")) {
System.out.println("received refresh request...");
outputWriter.write(this.filesToSend);
}
```

So, basically, the client side sends a simple message telling the server what it wants (in this case, "REFRESH" to retrieve the file list) and the server should give it to the client with its output writer.

What am I doing wrong? I suspect the problem is in the client side, since the "received refresh request..." does not print in the console.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because the PrintWriter messageWriter isn't flushing.
I would try.

```
 messageWriter.println("REFRESH");
 messageWriter.flush();
```

Comment: I thought PrintWriter outputWriter = new PrintWriter(
            theClientSocket.getOutputStream(), true); this statement made the PrintWriter automatically flush. I see that's not true. Thanks a lot.

Comment: A ok. That is true, but then you should your println so it creates a newline. Alternatively write("REFRESH\n"); would've worked as well. See the javadoc "autoFlush - A boolean; if true, the println, printf, or format methods will flush the output buffer". So not when you use a simple write.